# Should auto-generated "Possible duplicate" comments be deleted while close votes on a question are still pending?

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close

I just came across something I've not noticed before.

A question asked on July 28 (nine days ago as of now) has three active votes to "close as duplicate."

[Does time lapse of the sun damage the auto-focus sensors or components of a DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100345/15871)

Yet the auto-generated comments that indicate which questions were suggested as duplicates are nowhere to be found.

Does anyone know why those comments are not appearing?

Were they deleted manually by a mod?
Were they automatically deleted by a new system routine that is part of the recent updates that have been rolled out?

Note: Since one of those "close as duplicate of..." votes was mine, I can already affirm that at least one of those comments, auto-generated as a comment with my username, was not deleted by the user who voted to "close as duplicate."

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the first user to vote to close later deleted the autogenerated comment which was made on his behalf, so I guess he is allowed to delete it like any other comment.  Probably not ideal if 2 others voted to close with the same suggested alternate.

I'd guess existing behavior.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research!

Comment: I can confirm that the autogenerated comment can be edited or deleted by the user who owns it, because I've done both with autogenerated comments in my name on other stacks - although I did it to replace the comment with a more helpful one.